# Why was Frieza's 5-Minute Countdown so long?

Tags: dragon-ball

In his duel against Goku in Planet Namek, Frieza realizes he’s not winning his fight against Goku, so he say he’s going to make the planet self-destruct, and that the planet has five minutes before it explodes. Since Dragon Ball Z is a TV show, we could be nice and say the timing was off by a few minutes. Frieza’s timing is off: from 5 minutes to 5+ plus episodes. Why did his countdown take so long?

Is it because he was weakened in his 50% form that in his 70% form, he lost a certain percentage of his full power?

Comment: Maybe 1 Earth minute = 1 Namek Dragonball Z episode?

Answer (score 3):

Out of Universe explanation that was Akira Toriyama's way of heightening the drama.  He took a lot of time as well to show what was happening with the rest of the characters (Krillin, Gohan, etc).  The "Countdown" only advanced when the audience was watching the fright between Frieza and Goku.  Also the internal dialogue may seem like it takes a long time, but remember thoughts are fast!

The internal monologue is presented as spoken dialogue for the audience.  It takes much longer to speak out your thoughts than it does to think it.  Otherwise fights in Akira Toriyama's world would be over in less than a minute since all the Z fighters and their opponents move at superhuman speeds.

Comment: Talking is a free action!

Comment: Apparently, grabbing a Senzu bean and eating it is too!

Comment: I would like an actual cut to see just how long their fight lasts without all the side characters.

Comment: That 5 minute countdown scene is still be longer than 5 minutes.